# Tips for creating and editing paths in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path

I'm new to Adobe Illustrator, but  I have used extensively Inkscape. While I recognize that Illustrator is vastly superior in many fronts, I feel a bit of a lag  due to the need to use three or four different tools for creating and editing paths. I also find the handles extremely small.

So, I would like to ask for tips or advice, or even links, to how to deal with the (perhaps just perceived) extra difficulty in editing paths on Illustrator. Also, if it is possible at all to get bigger handles.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just discovered that a good mouse helps. One with assignable buttons, so that the pen tool (p) can be assigned to one button, and the same for "direct select", "curve" (shift-c) , and "=" for adding points.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts make living in Adobe so much easier.

I see you have most of them, but just to have a list:

- <kbd>P</kbd> = Pen tool
- <kbd>+</kbd> = Add Point
- <kbd>-</kbd> = Remove Point
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> = Convert Anchor Point tool
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> = Join two points
- <kbd>\</kbd> = Line Segment tool
- <kbd>M</kbd> = Create rectangle
- <kbd>L</kbd> = Create ellipse

While using the `Pen tool`, <kbd>Shift</kbd> locks into specific angles, Alt gives you quick access to the `Convert Anchor Point tool`, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> lets you move the whole object you're working on.

While creating rounded rectangles, polygons, or stars, see what happens when you use the up/down/left/right arrows as well as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> for the stars.

Comment: Learning the keyboard shortcuts definitely makes the hole process a lot smoother; once you're able to incorporate that into your workflow you'll find using paths in Illustrator a lot less of a chore.

Answer (score 7):

You can get slightly bigger handles and/or anchor points by selecting displays from the 4 boxes that I've highlighted.

The size difference isn't big, but it should help a little.

You can get to preferences from the top menu or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> <sup>( or <kbd>cmd</kbd> )</sup>

[image]

---

If you want help in other areas, you need to be a bit more specific.

For example: "In inkscape I was able to do *this* like *that*. How could I do it the same way in illustrator?"

---

This site could help a tiny tiny bit, even though it's meant for transfering from illustrator to inkscape.

http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Inkscape_for_Adobe_Illustrator_users

Comment: Hi thanks! Yes, I have already checked those options, even if the size difference is really small. Thanks also for the link, hopefully there will be one day a wiki for going the other way around.

Answer (score 2):

It might really help to use smart guides: `View > Smart Guides` or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. This way, if you hover over an object like an anchor, a small word appears, saying 'anchor'. Be sure that `Snap to Grid` is off: `View > Snap to Grid` or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>"</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Learn the shortcuts for the pen tool and think symmetrically when drawing.

### Think Symmetrically

If you're drawing a shape think about where you are placing anchors rather than just roughing out a shape. If you get familiar with how bezier paths are drawn you can plan ahead a bit when creating curves.

### Learn shortcuts especially for the drawing tools.

- space bar to move an anchor while you are clicking to place it
- option with the pen tool to start a non-symmetrical handle
- option-click a bezier handle with the pen tool to convert it from symmetrical to non-symmetrical
- Turn on the auto-add/delete option in the prefs in order to simply click a path to add an anchor or click an anchor to remove it.